# Pandas - Perform rolling average by group/sub-group

Tags: pandas, moving-average

I am trying to find the rolling average by grouping few columns. Given below is how my data set looks like:

```
category, sub_category,value
fruit, apple, 10
fruit, apple, 2
fruit, apple, 5
fruit, apple, 1
fruit, banana, 3
fruit, orange, 5
fruit, orange, 5
fruit, orange, 3
fruit, orange, 8
```

Expected output:

```
category, sub_category,value, rolling_average
fruit, apple, 10, 10
fruit, apple, 2, 6
fruit, apple, 5, 5.66
fruit, apple, 1, 2.66
fruit, banana, 3, 3
fruit, orange, 5, 5
fruit, orange, 5, 5
fruit, orange, 3, 4.33
fruit, orange, 8, 5.33
```

I am able to perform rolling average without any group but not sure how to perform by group within the same Dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - expanding mean with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349218/pandas-expanding-mean-with-groupby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`Expanding.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Expanding.mean.html) per groups:

```
df['expanding_average'] = (df.groupby(['category', 'sub_category'])['value']
                             .expanding()
                             .mean()
                             .reset_index(level=[0,1], drop=True))
print (df)
  category sub_category  value  expanding_average
0    fruit        apple     10          10.000000
1    fruit        apple      2           6.000000
2    fruit        apple      5           5.666667
3    fruit        apple      1           4.500000
4    fruit       banana      3           3.000000
5    fruit       orange      5           5.000000
6    fruit       orange      5           5.000000
7    fruit       orange      3           4.333333
8    fruit       orange      8           5.250000
```

Solution for rolling mean with `N=3`:

```
df['rolling_average'] = (df.groupby(['category', 'sub_category'])['value']
                           .rolling(3, min_periods=1)
                           .mean()
                           .reset_index(level=[0,1], drop=True))
print (df)

  category sub_category  value  rolling_average
0    fruit        apple     10        10.000000
1    fruit        apple      2         6.000000
2    fruit        apple      5         5.666667
3    fruit        apple      1         2.666667
4    fruit       banana      3         3.000000
5    fruit       orange      5         5.000000
6    fruit       orange      5         5.000000
7    fruit       orange      3         4.333333
8    fruit       orange      8         5.333333
```

Comment: if I may ask for another favour. Now that we are able to get the `rolling_average` I am trying to see if we can store the 3 values that are used to calculate the `rolling_average` in 3 separate columns. How could I modify the above to get those values. Thanks.