# Computing cumulative moving average over a Pandas data-frame with group-by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can solve this problem, but not in a pythonic way. Given the following dataframe:

```
   time  rssi  key1  key2  CMA
0  0.021 -71   P     A     NaN
1  0.022 -60   Q     A     NaN
2  0.025 -56   P     B     NaN
3  0.12  -70   Q     B     NaN
4  0.167 -65   P     A     NaN
5  0.210 -55   P     B     NaN
6  0.211 -74   Q     A     NaN
7  0.213 -62   Q     B     NaN
...
```

compute the cumulative moving average (CMA) of RSSI row by row, put the value in the column RSSI average. Iterate over increasing time, but group by `key1`, `key2`. This is equivalent to say that four CMA shall be computed: `(P,A)`, `(P,B)`, `(Q,A)`, `(Q,B)`. Finally, the CMA computed shall be put in the CMA column.

---

**Note 1**: I know RSSI average is not to be computed with this formula, I don't care about it.

**Note 2**: CMA formula is `avg(n) = (avg(n-1) * (n-1) + value(n))/n`

**Example 1:**

defines the `groupby()` strategy.

```
   time  rssi  key1  key2  CMA
0  0.021 -71   P     A     NaN <<-- first value can stay NaN or be default to rssi (i.e. -71)
4  0.167 -65   P     A     -68
...
```

**Example 2:**

desired output

```
   time  rssi  key1  key2  CMA
0  0.021 -71   P     A     NaN
1  0.022 -60   Q     A     NaN
2  0.025 -56   P     B     NaN
3  0.12  -70   Q     B     NaN
4  0.167 -65   P     A     -68
5  0.210 -55   P     B     -55.5
6  0.211 -74   Q     A     -67
7  0.213 -62   Q     B     -66
...
```

---

So far, this is what I can come up with

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['time'] = [0.021,0.022,0.025,0.12,0.167,0.210,0.211,0.213]
df['rssi'] = [-71,-60,-56,-70,-65,-55,-74,-62]
df['key1'] = ['P','Q','P','Q','P','P','Q','Q']
df['key2'] = ['A','A','B','B','A','B','A','B']
df["CMA"] = np.nan

for key, grp in df.groupby(['key1', 'key2']):
    i = 0
    old_index = 0
    for index, row in grp.iterrows():
        if i == 0:
            # allowed alternative
            df.at[index,'CMA'] = grp.at[index,'rssi']
            old_index = index
        else:
            df.at[index,'CMA'] = ((df.at[old_index,'CMA'] * i) + df.at[index,'rssi']) / (i+1)
            old_index = index
        i += 1

print df
```

works, but it's ugly. There must be a not-so-painful way to achieve the same in a more pythonic fashion. *How can I improve this without explicitly setting each cell value for that column?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - expanding mean with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349218/pandas-expanding-mean-with-groupby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `groupby().expanding().mean()` with a `reset_index`:

```
df['CMA'] = (df.groupby(['key1','key2'], 
                        as_index=False)['rssi']
               .expanding(min_periods=2).mean()
               .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
            )
```

Output:

```
    time  rssi key1 key2   CMA
0  0.021   -71    P    A   NaN
1  0.022   -60    Q    A   NaN
2  0.025   -56    P    B   NaN
3  0.120   -70    Q    B   NaN
4  0.167   -65    P    A -68.0
5  0.210   -55    P    B -55.5
6  0.211   -74    Q    A -67.0
7  0.213   -62    Q    B -66.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you walk me through it a little bit?

Comment: basically `groupby()['rssi']` groups the series by each unique pair `(key1, key2)`. For each group, `expanding().mean()` gives you the rolling mean. `reset_index()` bypasses the group number generated by `groupby()`.