# Expanding average per group ignoring previous n rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This if a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76065644/pandas-expanding-average-per-group-without-changing-the-order-of-the-rows/76066078).

I have the following dataframe:

```
       a  b
week       
8     10  9
9      3  8
9      5  5
9      7  2
10     1  3
9      4  4
9      2  6
```

I want to calculate the expanding average of each column, conditional on the index, but ignoring the previous n rows (including the current row). I also need to preserve the order of the rows of the original dataframe.
This is the expected output with n=2:

```
        a    b
week          
8     NaN  NaN
9     NaN  NaN
9     NaN  NaN
9     3.0  8.0
10    NaN  NaN
9     5.0  5.0
9     5.0  5.0
```

For example, the value of column "a" on the fourth row (3) is equal to the average of all preceding rows (excluding the third and fourth) where week = 9, so is equal to the value of column "a" in the second row.
The value of column "b" on the last row (5) is equal to the average of all preceding rows (excluding the last two) where week = 9, so is equal to the average of second, third and fourth row (8, 5, 2).

To better clarify, this is an excel representation of what I'm trying to do (using the last value of column "b" as a reference):
[image]

From the previous question, I know that I can get the conditional expanding average with the following:

```
(df.reset_index()
   .groupby('week')
   .expanding()
   .mean()
   .sort_index(level=1)
   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
```

In order to add the "ignore the previous 2 rows" feature, I tried to shift the original dataframe, but the output is not what I want:

```
(df.shift(2)
   .reset_index()
   .groupby('week')
   .expanding()
   .mean()
   .sort_index(level=1)
   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))

              a         b
week                     
8           NaN       NaN
9           NaN       NaN
9     10.000000  9.000000
9      6.500000  8.500000
10     5.000000  5.000000
9      6.666667  6.333333
9      5.250000  5.500000
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the computation. For column `a` the first value is `3`. Then why the next value is `5`, shouldn't it be `4` (`(3 + 5) / 2`) ?

Comment: The value for column "a" on the second-last row is (3 + 5 + 7) / 3. Since it's the sixth row, I only need to exclude from the average the fith and sixth rows, so I keep the second (3), third (5) and fourth (7). I added an excel representation: hope it's clearer now

Comment: Are you talking about the excel picture? I include the fith row because in the last row the range I can potentially draw from to calculate the mean goes from the first to the fith row (so I'm excluding the last 2 rows). But the excel formula also includes a conditional filter, keeping only rows where week = 9, so the first and the fith rows are actually dropped from the mean computation, which only considers the second, third and fourth rows. So, in excel terms, the formula becomes =AVERAGE(C7:C9)

Comment: I'm asking about problem statement. Usually when you exclude some rows, then those rows would come from the same group of those not being exclude.

Comment: Probably the previous excel picture was misleading. I changed the excel picture using the simpler average formula. I hope that makes it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
def fn(x, n = 2):
    idx = x.index[-1]
    x = x[:-n]
    return x[x.index == idx].mean()

x = df.expanding(1).apply(fn)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
        a    b
week          
8     NaN  NaN
9     NaN  NaN
9     NaN  NaN
9     3.0  8.0
10    NaN  NaN
9     5.0  5.0
9     5.0  5.0
```